# What is difference between public static and static public?

Tags: java

What is difference between `public static` and `static public`?

For example :

```
static public class MyClass....
```

Or

```
public static class MyClass....
```

Comment: There is no difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there's no difference in terms of functionality (byte code will be *exactly* the same) you *do* want to follow conventions, visit the [JLS - 8.3.1. Field Modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1):

```
FieldModifiers:
    FieldModifier
    FieldModifiers FieldModifier

FieldModifier: one of
    Annotation public protected private
    static final transient volatile
```

It'll be weird to see `static public`..

I also recommend you to visit [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html).

---

Edit:

Link from the same page to the `class` section:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1

Comment: For this specific question ClassModifier from 8.1.1 is more relevant (as the question asks about defining a class).

Answer (score 5):

[JLS 8.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1) :

> A class declaration may include class modifiers.
>
> ClassModifiers:
>       ClassModifier
>       ClassModifiers ClassModifier
>
> ClassModifier: one of
>       Annotation public protected private
>       abstract static final strictfp
>
> If two or more (distinct) class modifiers appear in a class declaration, then **it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above** in the production for ClassModifier.

So, `public static` is preferred, but the order doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing, in terms of functionality.

The language standard (JLS Java 8 SE edition) *allows* for them to be in any order but contains this section `8.1.1 Class modifiers`:

> **ClassModifier:** one of *Annotation,* public, protected, private, abstract, static, final, strictfp.
>
> If two or more (distinct) class modifiers appear in a class declaration, then it is customary,
>   though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the
>   production for ClassModifier.

So `public static` is the *preferred* option.

Comment: For this specific question ClassModifier from 8.1.1 is more relevant (as the question asks about defining a class).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, but dare I say that the de facto standard is `public static`. More importantly, be consistent throughout your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Java Language Specification, [section 8.1 Class Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1), you will see that there is no difference:

```
ClassDeclaration:
  NormalClassDeclaration
  EnumDeclaration

NormalClassDeclaration:
  {ClassModifier} class Identifier [TypeParameters] [Superclass] [Superinterfaces] ClassBody

ClassModifier:
  Annotation public protected private
  abstract static final strictfp
```

The [`{ClassModifier}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1) means that zero or more occurrences of one of the ClassModifier values is allowed (see [2.4 Grammar Notation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.4)).

[Section 8.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1) also explicitly says:

> It is a compile-time error if the same keyword appears more than once as a modifier for a class declaration.
>
> If two or more (distinct) class modifiers appear in a class declaration, then **it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above** in the production for `ClassModifier`.